# Programmatically create a menu

Tags: navigation

How can I programmatically create a menu? I have 3 different menus I want to create: The first menu will be placed in the top left of the header; the second menu will be placed below the first menu; the third menu will be the main navigation.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are trying to do this in an update script, this should work:

```
$menus = array(
  array(
    'menu_name' => 'menu_test_one',
    'title' => 'My Menu One',
    'description' => 'Lorem Ipsum',
  ),
  array(
    'menu_name' => 'menu_test_two',
    'title' => 'My Menu Two',
    'description' => 'Lorem Ipsum',
  ),
  array(
    'menu_name' => 'menu_test_three',
    'title' => 'My Menu Three',
    'description' => 'Lorem Ipsum',
  ),
);

$links = array(
  array(
    array(
      'link_title' => 'Link1',
      'link_path' => 'http://yourdomain.com/link1',
      'menu_name' => 'menu_test_one',
      'weight' => 0,
      'expanded' => 0,
    ),
    array(
      'link_title' => 'Link2',
      'link_path' => 'http://yourdomain.com/link2',
      'menu_name' => 'menu_test_one',
      'weight' => 1,
      'expanded' => 0,
    ),
  ),
  array(
    array(
      'link_title' => 'Link3',
      'link_path' => 'http://yourdomain.com/link3',
      'menu_name' => 'menu_test_two',
      'weight' => 0,
      'expanded' => 0,
    ),
    array(
      'link_title' => 'Link4',
      'link_path' => 'http://yourdomain.com/link4',
      'menu_name' => 'menu_test_two',
      'weight' => 1,
      'expanded' => 0,
    ),
  ),
  array(
    array(
      'link_title' => 'Link5',
      'link_path' => 'http://yourdomain.com/link5',
      'menu_name' => 'menu_test_three',
      'weight' => 0,
      'expanded' => 0,
    ),
    array(
      'link_title' => 'Link6',
      'link_path' => 'http://yourdomain.com/link6',
      'menu_name' => 'menu_test_three',
      'weight' => 1,
      'expanded' => 0,
    ),
  ),
);

// Save menu group into menu_custom table
foreach ($menus as $menu) {
  // Look the table first if the data does exist
  $exists = db_query("SELECT title FROM {menu_custom} WHERE menu_name=:menu_name", array(':menu_name' => $menu['menu_name']))->fetchField();
  // Save the record if the data does not exist
  if (!$exists) {
    menu_save($menu);
  }
}

$item = ''; 
foreach ($links as $layer1) {
  foreach ($layer1 as $link) {
    // Build an array of menu link 
    $item = array(
      'link_path' => $link['link_path'],
      'link_title' => $link['link_title'],
      'menu_name' => $link['menu_name'],
      'weight' => $link['weight'],
      'expanded' => $link['expanded'],
    );
    // Look the table first if the data does exist
    $exists = db_query("SELECT mlid from {menu_links} WHERE link_title=:link_title AND link_path=:link_path", array(':link_title' =>  $link['link_title'], ':link_path' => $link['link_path']))->fetchField();
    // Save the record if the data does not exist
    if (!$exists) {  
      menu_link_save($item);
    }
  }
}
```

Comments are welcome if my approach is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Let me try your code and will give feedback later. Thanks for sharing

Comment: Instead of running the $exists db query a more future proof (but maybe slightly slower) method would be to just use if (!menu_load($menu['menu_name'])) { menu_save($menu); }

Comment: Cool, nice one!

Comment: My suggestion would be to use [menu_get_menus()](http://api.drupal.org/menu_get_menus) instead of a query. Then you can save the menus to a var and simply do an `if (!array_key_exists($menu, $menus)) {` - also adding the single param FALSE to menu_get_menus() returns only custom menus.

Comment: you should also make sure that page with target URL exist on the page if you will use not absolute URL. Otherwise you will not see link

Comment: Also when you check if the menu link exist:
// Look the table first if the data does exist
    $exists = ...
You need also to check for menu_name as the same link combination can be in different menus.

Comment: Why is it necessary to check if the menu exists? `menu_save` already does a `db_merge` and checks the status of the menu. If it exists, it updates. If it does not exist, it creates the menu.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to easily populate a menu from an array :

```
<?php
function populate_menu($links, $menu_name, $plid = 0) {
  foreach ($links as $link) {
    $ls = array(
      'menu_name' => $menu_name,
      'link_title' => $link['link_title'],
      'link_path' => $link['link_path'],
      'plid' => $plid,
    );
    $newpid = menu_link_save($ls);
    if (!empty($link['childs'])) {
      populate_menu($link['childs'], $menu_name, $newpid);
    }
  }
}


$items = array(
  array(
    'link_title' => 'Menu1',
    'link_path' => '<front>',
    'childs' => array(
      array(
        'link_title' => 'Sub Item 1',
        'link_path' => '<front>',
        'childs' => array(
          array(
            'link_title' => 'Link item 1',
            'link_path' => '<front>',
          ),
          array(
            'link_title' => 'Link item 2',
            'link_path' => '<front>',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      array(
        'link_title' => 'Sub Item 2',
        'link_path' => '<front>',
        'childs' => array(
          array(
            'link_title' => 'Link item',
            'link_path' => '<front>',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
populate_menu($items, 'main-menu');
```

Answer (score 2):

[`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) is all you need to implement in you custom module. For creation of custom module, refer to [this documentation](http://drupal.org/node/1074362).

```php
//Define the menus in the function which goes in your MYMODULE.module file

function MYMODULE_menu() {
  //the menu which will point to http://yoursite/first-menu
  $items['first-menu'] = array(
    'title' => 'First menu',  // will appear as the name of the link
    // Page callback, etc. need to be added here.
  );

  //the menu which will point to http://yoursite/second-menu
  $items['second-menu'] = array(
    'title' => 'Second menu',  // will appear as the name of the link
    // Page callback, etc. need to be added here.
  );

  //the menu which will point to http://yoursite/third-menu
  $items['third-menu'] = array(
    'title' => 'third menu',  // will appear as the name of the link
    // Page callback, etc. need to be added here.
  );

  return $items;
}
```

You could print the menu in any region by adding the following code to the `page.tpl.php` file of you theme.

```php
// Add this line in <div id="header"></div> to print it in header.
<?php
$menu1 = menu_navigation_links('first-menu');
print theme('links__first_menu', array('links' => $menu1));

//Print the second menu right after the first menu.
$menu2 = menu_navigation_links('second-menu');
print theme('links__second_menu', array('links' => $menu1));
?>
```

You don't need to print the third menu because by default it will appear on the navigation menu.

#### Note

This is not the best practice for creating a navigation menu and adding it to a page. `hook_menu()` is for creating page callbacks and not for creating navigation menus. Please read [Menu system](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/group/menu/7.x), which explains the differences. I answered this when I had started to learn Drupal and I don't recommend this answer anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the [Menu Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_import) module. It's very cool and easy for menu deployment.
You can create menu by hands on your website and use generated JSON. Also you can create nodes for non-existing pages.

Here is example of export script:

```
$menu_name = 'menu-footer-secondary-menu';

// Create menu if doesn't exist.
if (!menu_load($menu_name)) {
  $menu = array(
    'menu_name' => $menu_name,
    'title' => t('Footer secondary menu'),
    'description' => '',
  );
  menu_save($menu);
}

// Import menu links from JSON.
$menu_string = 'Impressum {"url":"node\/1","options":{"attributes":[]}}
Datenschutzbestimmungen {"url":"node\/2","options":{"attributes":[]}}
Nutzungsbedingungen {"url":"node\/3","options":{"attributes":[]}}
';

$options = array(
  //'link_to_content' => TRUE, // Look for existing nodes and link to them.
  'create_content' => TRUE, // Create new content (also if link_to_content not set).
  'remove_menu_items' => TRUE, // Removes current menu items.
  'node_type' => 'page',
  'node_body' => 'Page is in development...',
  'node_author' => 1,
  'node_status' => 1,
);

menu_import_string($menu_string, $menu_name, $options);
```

You can run this script with [hook_update_N()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7) or [Update script processor](https://www.drupal.org/project/updatescripts)

Answer (score 0):

For creating a menu block, in your .install file add the following code. (Replace *mymodule* with the module machine name.)

```php
function mymodule_enable() {
  $t = get_t();

  if (module_exists('menu')) {
    menu_save(array(
      'menu_name' => 'my-new-menu',
      'title' => $t('My New Menu'),
      'description' => $t('My Menu description'),
    ));
  }
}

function mymodule_uninstall() {
  if (module_exists('menu')) {
    if ($my_menu = menu_load('my-new-menu')) {
     menu_delete($my_menu);
    }
  }
}
```

In the .module file, add this code.

```php
function mymodule_menu() {
  return array(
   'mypage' => array(
   'title' => 'My Page',        
   'description' => 'My Page description',    
   'page callback' => 'my_page_callback_func',
   'page arguments' => array(arg(0)),
   'access arguments' => array('access content'),
   'menu_name' => 'my-new-menu',
   'file' => 'my.new.page.inc',
   'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/includes',
  ),
 );     
}
```