# How to create parent child menu programatically?

Tags: routes, taxonomy-terms

I have an array like this :

```
Array(
  [0] => Array(
    [link_title] => Level == bod
    [link_path] => link1
    [menu_name] => parrent-child-menu
    [weight] => 1
    [expanded] => 1
  )
)
Array(
  [0] => Array(
    [link_title] => Level == About// us///
    [link_path] => link1
    [menu_name] => parrent-child-menu
    [weight] => 3
    [expanded] => 1
  )
)
Array(
  [0] => Array(
    [link_title] => Level == name12
    [link_path] => link1
    [menu_name] => parrent-child-menu
    [weight] => 5
    [expanded] => 1
  )
)
Array(
  [0] => Array(
    [link_title] => Level == name13
    [link_path] => link1
    [menu_name] => parrent-child-menu
    [weight] => 5
    [expanded] => 1
  )
)
Array(
  [0] => Array(
    [link_title] => Level == name14
    [link_path] => link1
    [menu_name] => parrent-child-menu
    [weight] => 5
    [expanded] => 1
  )
)
```

I want it in the following format:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [link_title] => Level == bod
            [link_path] => link1
            [menu_name] => parrent-child-menu
            [weight] => 1
            [expanded] => 1
            [children] => 
                    Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [link_title] => Level == About// us///
                                    [link_path] => link1
                                    [menu_name] => parrent-child-menu
                                    [weight] => 3
                                    [expanded] => 1
                                    [children] => 
                                            Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [link_title] => Level == name12
                                                            [link_path] => link1
                                                            [menu_name] => parrent-child-menu
                                                            [weight] => 5
                                                            [expanded] => 1
                                                        )

`)
                                            Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [link_title] => Level == name13
                                                        [link_path] => link1
                                                        [menu_name] => parrent-child-menu
                                                        [weight] => 5
                                                        [expanded] => 1
                                                    )

                                            )
                                            Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [link_title] => Level == name14
                                                        [link_path] => link1
                                                        [menu_name] => parrent-child-menu
                                                        [weight] => 5
                                                        [expanded] => 1
                                                    )

                                            )
                            )

                    )
    )`

)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of `plid` to the `mlid` of the parent link. For example, you need to have this kind of menu structure.

```
About
  Vision
  Mission
  History
```

To create that programmatically you need first to create the `About` then get the `mlid`. After that you are good to create the `Vision`, `Mission`, and `History` as you have the `About` `mlid` already. Please see [menu_link_save](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_link_save/7).
Check this related [thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41570/create-a-menu-programmatically-in-drupal-7) as well.

Answer (score 0):

See below example, hope you will get the solution to create parent-child menu programmatically.

```
$items['hotels'] = array(
'title' => 'Hotel Process',
'page callback' => 'hotels_page',
'access arguments' => array('access content'),
'weight' => 1,
);
$items['hotels/hotels2'] = array(
'title' => 'Hotel Statistics',
'page callback' => 'hotels_page',
'access arguments' => array('access content'),
'weight' => 1,
);
```

This also works:

```
$items['hotels'] = array(
'children' => array('hotels2'),
'title' => 'Hotel Process',
'page callback' => 'hotels_page',
'access arguments' => array('access content'),
'weight' => 1,
);
$items['hotels/hotels2'] = array(
'parent' => array('hotels'),
'title' => 'Hotel Statistics',
'page callback' => 'hotels_page',
'access arguments' => array('access content'),
'weight' => 1,
);
```